# Debug angular 2 typescript application in IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-cli

I can easily debug my Angular 2 (from an Angular-CLI generated project) Typescript files in Chrome and Firefox but I am unable to debug any of my typescript file in IE 11. All files I can see in the list are of type `.js` Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong or how to debug the application in IE?

Comment: Consider using polyfills to enable IE11 compatibility https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills. Are you using angular-cli? Is your application Angular 4?

Answer (score 7):

in IE 11 you need to open your .ts file in debugger it found under "Dynamic Scripts".

[image: Dynamic Scripts]

scroll down to and locate your .ts file and open it in debug.

[image: Select you file]

Comment: And what if my *.ts files are not there? I can only debug typescript on Chrome

Answer (score 4):

IE 11 wont handle the maps files for you automatically like Chrome does. So you have to choose the `map` file manually by right clicking on the `js` file tab:

[image]

then you should be able to debug your `.ts` file

[image]

However after the app gets reloaded you have to choose the source map file again, that is just wired experience and I would not recommend to debug you app in IE 11 at all unless you are experiencing some specific IE 11 bug.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the only way to debug **.ts** files with IE 11 is to create your own mappings between your **.ts** files and your transpiled/minified **.js** files, by creating **.map** files.

The feature is available only for **Windows 8.1 and higher**.

More information [in the official doc, at the "Source maps" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v=vs.85)#source_maps).

Answer (score 0):

Set value "sourceMap" to true in angular.json file of your application.